# Gradual fading by drawing a transparent rectangle repeatedly

Tags: java, colors, processing, alphablending

This is a question about [Processing.org](http://processing.org).

I am fading out previously drawn objects by drawing a semi-transparent white rectangle over the view for every frame.

However, it appears that they never fade to completely white.  The fading has a fixed point at some noticeably non-white shade of grey.  Same thing happens when trying to fade to black.

Is this a standard feature of how alpha-blending works in processing?  Is there a *relatively easy* way around it, to achieve a completely white background (given enough steps)?

I imagined the resulting colour would be a linear combination of the colours that are blended, which means the limit should be white.  Perhaps the non-white fixed point is an artefact of rounding?

Sample code illustrating the issue:

```
void setup() {
  size(300,300);
  background(0);
  noStroke();
  frameRate(15);
}

void draw() {
  fill(255,10);
  rect(0,0,width,height);
  fill(255);
  rect(0,0,50,50); // for comparison to white
}
```

*edit:* added *java* tag in hope of more attention

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem yet?

Comment: @LaserJesus Not really, I've stopped playing with it.  The reason why it doesn't fade to complete white is that colours are encoded as integers (i.e. no fractional values are allowed).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whats going on, it seems like you should be right and that if the number of rectangles drawn * the alpha value of those rectangles is greater than 255 it should be completely white. Anyways why not just redraw every frame (like i do by moving the background(0) line into the draw loop) and then just increase your alpha value. I think this path will give you more control in your animations in the future.

```
int a;

void setup() {
  size(300,300);
  noStroke();
  frameRate(15);
  a = 0;
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  a += 1;
  if(a<=255){
    fill(255,a);
  }
  rect(0,0,width,height);
  fill(255);
  rect(0,0,50,50); // for comparison to white
}
```

Comment: My point was not to just fade out a rectangle, but to gradually fade out *everything* that was drawn on the screen so far, all of this while still drawing new things.  Imagine moving a "ball" through the screen, and not deleting the ball drawn in the previous frame, but instead just "fading it out" a bit.  The end result will be that the ball will leave a fading trail.  This can make a nice effect for more complex animations.  The approach you outlined can only produce a fading rectangle, not this effect.

Answer (score 0):

I did a lot of digging and now I am rather confident to say, that complete fading with the alpha channel is not possible. There is however a thing called brightness, so let's use it.

```
void setup() {
  size(300,300);
  background(0);
  noStroke();
  frameRate(15);

  // White rectangle for fading comparison.
  fill(255);
  rect(0, 0, 50, 50);
}

void draw() {
  fade(10);
}

void fade(final int fadeSpeed) {
  loadPixels();
  for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < width; col++) {
      final int pixelIndex = row * width + col;
      int pixel = pixels[pixelIndex];
      int red   = ((pixel >>> 16) & 0xFF) + fadeSpeed;
      int green = ((pixel >>>  8) & 0xFF) + fadeSpeed;
      int blue  =  (pixel         & 0xFF) + fadeSpeed;
      if (red   > 255) { red   = 255; }
      if (green > 255) { green = 255; }
      if (blue  > 255) { blue  = 255; }

      // Shift bits back into propper position and 
      red   <<= 16;
      green <<=  8;
      pixel &= 0xFF000000;  // Keep alpha bits.
      pixel |= red |= green |= blue;

      pixels[pixelIndex] = color(pixel);
    }
  }
  updatePixels();
}
```

By incrementing all three color channels (red, green, blue) at the same time we don't change color but brightness.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that, while the rounding error (if that's what it is) applies to pretty much everything you can try, using `blendMode(SUBTRACT)`, followed by a fill with a very small greyscale color (like `fill(2)`) achieves a gradual fade over many `draw()` cycles without the "ghost" image that all the other approaches seem to have, while keeping the frame rate up (which is often critical in real-time drawing situations).

```
 // The only reasonable way to actually "fade" out the pixels.
blendMode(SUBTRACT);
fill(2);
rect(0, 0, width, height);
blendMode(NORMAL);
```